# CSS: Why is this div % width not working?

Tags: css

In [this page](http://freightplus.com/beta/example4.html), when the view port is decreased to 1024px or less, the `div#boxes` has a width of 20%, but it is not being displayed at 20% of its parent width. It is displayed at 20% of something far smaller, which I cannot work out.

[image]

Can you please help me determine why `div#boxes` is not displaying @ 20% of `#front-page-slide`'s width?

Comment: You should add your HTML tag and CSS code for this too.

Comment: Something else is probably pushing the view somehow-- figure out why the size of the parent perhaps.  But Huy is correct-- you will need to post some code.  Most people are probably a bit hesitant to click to some random URL you've posted-- I'd prefer to see the code here, or work in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or a [codepen.io](http://www.codepen.io) or other known site.

Comment: without looking too deep i think its the table inside the #boxes it has a width set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be related with a lot of code on that element... As you're using `display: table-cell` on the parent element, and the sibling (`#slider`) has the width already setup, there's no need to redefine the width for the remaining element, so... if you remove the 20% with from the media query `@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)` (line 155 from the file mhm-style.css), it will work a lot better.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div#boxes` **is displaying at 20% of `#front-page-slide`'s width**. It only appears as if it's not because it is "misplaced" by the CSS styling.

Add this CSS to change the div#boxes CSS for screen width of or smaller than 1024px (I also tried it via my browser dev tool and it works. see attached screenshot):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    display: inherit;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]